# Insert an AVG() Value from a table into the same table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have one table named Test with columns named ID,Name,UserValue,AverageValue

ID,Name,UserValue,AverageValue (As Appears on Table)
1,a,10,NULL
2,a,20,NULL
3,b,5,NULL
4,b,10,NULL
5,c,25,NULL

I know how to average the numbers via `(SELECT Name, AVG(UserValue) FROM Test GROUP BY Name)`
Giving me:

Name,Column1(AVG(Query)) (As Appears on GridView1 via databind when I run the website)
a,15
b,7.5
c,25

What I need to do is make the table appear as such by inserting the calculated AVG() into the AverageValue column server side:

ID,Name,UserValue,AverageValue (As Appears on Table)
1,a,10,15
2,a,20,15
3,b,5,7.5
4,b,10,7.5
5,c,25,25

Conditions:
The AVG(UserValue) must be inserted into Test table AverageValue.
If new entries are made the AverageValue would be updated to match AVG(UserValue).

So what I am looking for is a SQL command that is something like this:
`INSERT INTO Test (AverageValue) VALUES (SELECT Name, AVG(UserValue) FROM Test GROUP BY Name)`

I have spent considerable amount of time searching on google to find an example but have had no such luck. Any examples would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Is ther a reason that you need to hardcode this value into the table, rather that building a VIEW on top of the table? I.e. use dynamic SQL rather that storign the caclucated field.

Comment: Agreed, I see no reason to *store* the average when you're just going to be forced to re-calculate it *every time* any row changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, avg(uservalue) over (partition by name) as newavg
      from test t
     )
update toupdate
    set AverageValue = newavg;
```

The CTE `toupdate` is an updatable CTE, so you can just use it in an update statement as if it were a table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will do the trick for you. I use the merge statement a lot! It's perfect for doing things like this.

Peace,
Katherine

```
use [test_01];

go

if object_id (N'tempdb..##test', N'U') is not null
    drop table ##test;

go

create table ##test (
    [id]            [int] identity(1, 1) not null,
    [name]          [nvarchar](max) not null,
    [user_value]    [int] not null,
    [average_value] [decimal](5, 2),
    constraint [pk_test_id] primary key([id])
  );

go

insert into ##test
        ([name], [user_value])
values      (N'a',10),
            (N'a',20),
            (N'b',5),
            (N'b',10),
            (N'c',25);

go

with [average_builder] as (select [name],
            avg(cast([user_value] as [decimal](5, 2))) as [average_value]
     from   ##test
     group  by [name])
merge into ##test as target
using [average_builder] as source
on target.[name] = source.[name]
when matched then
    update set target.[average_value] = source.[average_value];

go

select [id], [name], [user_value], [average_value] from ##test;

go
```